# How do I substract values from an UNION query in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union

My UNION query is:

```
SELECT type, hs
FROM (...) as table_1

UNION

SELECT type, hs
FROM (...) as table_2

UNION 

SELECT type, hs
FROM (...) as table_3
```

What i want to do is:

```
SELECT 
table_1.hs hs_1, 
table_2.hs hs_2,
table_3.hs - (table_1.hs + table_2.hs) hs_3
FROM ()
```

Just tell me if I have explained myself correctly.

** Edited

As asked, I add more details:

Rows from UNION of all 3 tables are:

```
type   | hs
___________
'BLUE' | 8
'RED'  | 2
'ALL'  | 15
```

What i need is:

```
type   | hs
___________
'BLUE' | 8
'RED'  | 2
'REST' | 5
```

'REST' value is obtained from substracting the addition of 'RED' (2) + 'BLUE' (8) from ALL (15)

In Postgresql, something like:

```
SELECT 
table_1.hs hs_1, 
table_2.hs hs_2,
table_3.hs - (table_1.hs + table_2.hs) hs_3
FROM ()
```

Comment: could you give a few lines of sample data for each table and show what the expected output should be. also, look at `EXCEPT`. That keyword implements set difference in sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `CTE` to get the `UNION` result set. then use `CASE WHEN` and subquery make your logic.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
   type varchar(50),
  hs int
);

CREATE TABLE T2(
   type varchar(50),
  hs int
);

CREATE TABLE T3(
   type varchar(50),
  hs int
);




INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('BLUE',8);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('RED' , 2);
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES ('ALL' , 15);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH CTE AS (

  SELECT type, hs
   FROM T1
   UNION
   SELECT type, hs
   FROM T2
   UNION 
   SELECT type, hs
   FROM T3
)
SELECT CASE WHEN type = 'ALL' 
             THEN 'REST'
          ELSE type END,
          CASE WHEN type = 'ALL' 
             THEN hs - (SELECT SUM(hs) FROM CTE WHERE type in ('RED','BLUE'))
          ELSE hs END
FROM CTE;

| type | hs  |
| ---- | --- |
| RED  | 2   |
| REST | 5   |
| BLUE | 8   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xj3QdQGUbXome12EoEugEp/0)

Comment: Thank you very much! Really advance answer!! Thank you and big hug from Argentina!

Comment: No problem glad to help :)